# Attempting an inner join; showing up with an error or no rows returned?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

I'm a beginner in SQL and currently I'm using MySQL Workbench to experiment with databases. I have made five tables and have attempted to inner join two of them, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I'm trying to join the table "villager_name" to "villager_species." I set up my foreign keys associated to my other tables in my "villager_name" table, including the species table.

For reference:
[Villager Name Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHbZA.png)
[Villager Species Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GWyY.png)
and I have nine values in all of my tables.

For my inner join, I used

```
select * from villager_name
INNER JOIN villager_species
ON villager_name.vname = villager_species.species;
```

Initially, I used "name" instead of "vname" but it gave me an error, presumably because it's a claimed word. I changed it to "vname" instead and ran it.
When I try this, 0 rows are returned. Eventually, I want to be able to join all of my tables together to be able to view all of the data, but I need to get this basic syntax/idea down first.

[Name table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eYLw.png)
[Species table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQZTq.png)

Comment: Your query is fine which means there are no rows which match the on condition. Please add the contents of the 2 tables as text to the question as well as the table definitions and expected output - all as text.

Comment: Please use text, not images/links, for what can be given via text. For code questions give a [mre].  [help] [ask]

Comment: As already said in 2 comments, give text, not images/links. Please don't put "please", "thanks", etc in posts. For code questions give a [mre]--which includes cut & paste & runnable code. [ask] [help]

Comment: In code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization. When you get a result that you don't expect, find out what your misunderstanding is.--Isolate the first erroneous subexpression & its input & output. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is OK, however it looks like you are not joining on the right columns.

It is not possible to tell for sure without seeing your actual data, but from the structures of your table, it looks like the relation you built is : `villager_name(fk_idvillager_species)` -> `villager_species(pk_idvillager_species)`.

If so, your query should be:

```
select * 
from villager_name vn
INNER JOIN villager_species vs 
    on vs.pk_idvillager_species = vn.pk_idvillager_species;
```

Notes:

- using (meaningful) table aliases (here, `vn` for `villager_name` and `vs` for `villager_species`) makes the query easier to read and write
- generally speaking, using `select *` is not recommended; it is better to list the columns you want to output in the `from` clause (this also gives you the opportunity to alias column names to avoid possible clashes)

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I will definitely shorten the table aliases. I tried to use the query and it didn't work initially, but I realized that it should be "vn.fk_idvillager_species" instead of using "pk" for primary key. I tried that and my tables came up, but no results were returned. Maybe this is a MySQL Workbench software issue? Or maybe I'm missing something...

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out why it wasn't populating, so I literally just inserted each value into the table with

```
update villager_name set fk_idvillager_species = 1, fk_idvillager_personality = 1,fk_idvillager_style = 1,fk_idvillager_zodiac =1 
where pk_idvillagername = 1;
```

And I just changed the numbers 1-9. I'm sure there is a quicker/shorter way to do this, however. After I finished doing that, I used my join statement and it did what I wanted it to. Instead of using the * though, I specified the tables so I'm  not just pulling up a bunch of columns without values.